# Nexus 4 flash stock kernel when it's stuck in bootloader

Tags: nexus-4, unbricking

I screwed myself over when I flashed broken files to the recovery and kernel partitions. I want to get back my stock kernel, but I can only get it to either the bootloader or Download Mode. Adb and Fastboot can't find it, and LGNPST says the dongle is not connected. I tried from Windows 7 and from Linux Lite 1.0.8 (basically Ubuntu 12.04). My bootloader is unlocked. What should I do? 
The only solution I can come up with is to take it apart, desolder the rom chip, flash to it from something else, and put it back in. Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Use wugfresh's great kit, you can also flash from a bootloop with it and it will find the stock image you select for you

Does a massive amount of other stuff too, root, TWRP recovery etc. I have flashed several custom roms with it

www.wugfresh.com/nrt/

Edit:

Flash from a softbricked/bootloop state

[image]

Comment: Could you post ([edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/107042/edit)) the instructions as well? I know they are in the link, but they can't be reached if the link goes down for some reason in future.